# How to make Lisp input case sensitive

Tags: lisp

I'm programming in lisp. The function I'm working on is appending two lists together, and it works.

However, the output also comes back as uppercase letters, and when. I use an escape symbol, the lowercase letters are surrounded by '|' symbols. Here is an example:

"Input your first list"

(a b)

"Input another list"

( \a \b)

Output: (A B |a| |b|)

I want it to be (a b a b).

Is there a way to input things differently or write a function to fix this?
My current REPL stores the input as a variable, runs it through the function, and outputs it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All symbols are interned as upper case by default.  When you write `defun`, it is read as `DEFUN` internally, for example, and that is the symbol with the symbol-name string `"DEFUN"`.

There are two ways for *ad hoc* overriding this reading behaviour: you can escape single characters in symbols with `\`, or you can escape multiple characters by enclosing them in pipes `|…|`.  Escaped characters are taken as they are entered, and can be *any* characters.  `|This is a valid symbol.|` and its symbol-name is `"This is a valid symbol."`.

So, each of these becomes the symbol whose symbol-name is "Abc":

```
a\b\c
a|bc|
|Abc|
```

Now, the *printer* prints symbols in such a way that when read in by the *reader* they are the same symbol.  So, if there are any lower-case or non-constituent characters in the symbol name, they need to be escaped in one of the ways shown above.  My SBCL uses the last option.

You can customize the read/print behaviour through the readtable.  For example, you can set the readtable-case to `:preserve`:

```
(defun foo ()
  (let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable *readtable*)))
    (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)
    (print (append (read) (read)))))
```

If you now run `(foo)`, then enter `(a b)` and `(A B)`, first `(a b A B)` is printed, and then the REPL prints the returned list as `(|a| |b| A B)` because we made sure to change only a lexically scoped copy of the actual readtable.

You can read up on this in the Hyperspec and play around with it a bit.  If you have an actual problem to solve, we'll have to see how to best address it.